# Magento redirects to Homepage when i search for products Using REST tokens

Tags: magento-1.9, rest-api

I have searched for the products like this `localhost/api/rest/products`

But it is directly redirecting to Homepage of `localhost`. I have generated all the keys and tokens and i tried this also: `127.0.0.1/rest/api/products`

Comment: Does _ANY_ rest request work?

Comment: No sir...Nothing works ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://www.ask-sheldon.com/magento-enable-rest-api-in-htaccess/

Did you activate the REST Api in .htaccess?

1. change  `Options +FollowSymLinks` to `Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews`
2. uncomment  `RewriteRule ^api api.php?type=rest [QSA,L]`

Comment: If Adrians or my answer solved your problem, please mark it as solution.

Comment: Actually I dont know ..How to do that sir

Comment: Welcome to MageOverflow Sudhir! :-)

Comment: I've tried this but still it will redirect to the homepage. Is there anything else?

Answer (score 4):

The path is localhost/**api/rest**/products.

Comment: Much of the documentation doesn't mention this. Thanks!!